# How do you source neovim config file without restarting nvim?

Tags: bash, vim, zsh, neovim

Is there a way to source the `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` file from within nvim?

With vanilla vim you can source .vimrc with `:so %` : Is there an equivalent method do with similarly in neovim?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`$MYVIMRC` is always available from inside vim or neovim, so you can just use

`:source $MYVIMRC`

and bind it to a convenient mapping:

`nnoremap <Leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<CR>`

2021 update: If you are using neovim with a lua config, you can use `:luafile $MYVIMRC`

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing, didn't know about `$MYVIMRC`. In my setup I have multiple files lua files which I import from the entry-point `init.lua`. I noticed that executing `:so` nor `:luafile` didn't recursively source changes I made in the other files. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: @VladislavKovechenkov are you using something like this `vim.cmd('luafile ~/.config/lvim/lua/mappings.lua')`?

Answer (score 5):

How about use the map

```
let $my_vimrc = $localappdata.'\nvim\init.vim'
nnoremap <leader>s :source $my_vimrc<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks. I discovered that the variable $MYVIMRC is already set by default  so you can just use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Neovim you can do something like :

```lua
local bind = vim.keymap.set
bind("n", "<leader>s", ":source $HOME/.config/nvim/init.lua <CR>")
```

But it's not use with Lazy.nvim